# jQuery ajax upon updating textfield cant change textfield again

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am an bit lost on the following thing.
I have this piece of code,

Fleet.php

```
function sendData(nr) {
var data = $("#myform" + nr).serialize();

console.log(data);

$("#myForm" + nr).submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "inc/FleetData.php",
    datatype: "html",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success:function(data)
    {
        if(data) {
            //$("#fleet").load(window.location + " #fleet");
            $('#fleet').html(data);
            //alert(data);
        } else {
            //$("#fleet").load(window.location + " #container");
            //alert("Something is wrong with the update of the collor. Please notify an admin");
            //alert(data);
        }
    }
});
}
```

the form

```
<div class="rTablecell" style="background-color: #'.$row['train_row_color'].'";>
                <form method="post" action="" id="myform' . ++$i . '" onchange="sendData('.$i.');"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="update" />
                    <input type="text" name="value" value="'.$row['train_name'].'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="field" value="train_name"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Now for the first time I change the value it will post the values to fleetData.php,
then it will load the div.
After that I can change the value but it will not send the data to fleetData.php,
this is only happening with textfields and not with select fields.

Edit:
Select Fields

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform' . ++$i . '">
                <input type="hidden" name="update" value="update" />
                <select class="test" name="value" onchange="sendData('.$i.');" style="background-color: #'.$row['train_row_color'].';"> 
                <option value="" style="background-color: #ffffff"'; if($row['train_row_color'] == "") { echo 'selected'; } echo '></option>
                <option value="ff0000" style="background-color: #ff0000"'; if($row['train_row_color'] == "ff0000") { echo 'selected'; } echo '>Red</option>
                <option value="3000ff" style="background-color: #3000ff"'; if($row['train_row_color'] == "3000ff") { echo 'selected'; } echo '>Blue</option>
                <option value="36ff00" style="background-color: #36ff00"'; if($row['train_row_color'] == "36ff00") { echo 'selected'; } echo '>Green</option>
                <option value="e400ff" style="background-color: #e400ff"'; if($row['train_row_color'] == "e400ff") { echo 'selected'; } echo '>Purple</option>
                <option value="fff000" style="background-color: #fff000"'; if($row['train_row_color'] == "fff000") { echo 'selected'; } echo '>Yellow</option>
                <input type="hidden" name="field" value="train_row_color" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
                </select>
                </form>
```

Comment: where are select fields in your form?

Comment: Added the select fields to my original post

Comment: I doubt that `form` has onchange event.

Comment: if i change it so its on the textfield instead it wont work at all. it needs to be set at the form function in order to submit the form if there is an onchange. tough i agree that it should be at the text field. hmm

Answer (score 0):

Couple things, you should be doing an event listener rather than an inline script, you should change on a `class` rather than `id`, and you should remove the `input` fields from the `select`:

```
# Might also be less code to do this once in a function
function setSelected($value,$is)
{
    return ($value == $is)? ' selected="selected"' : '';
}

?>
<form method="post" action="" class="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field" value="train_row_color" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
    <select class="test" name="value" style="background-color: #<?php echo $row['train_row_color'] ?>">
        <option value="" style="background-color: #ffffff"<?php echo setSelected($row['train_row_color'],"") ?>><?php echo $row['train_row_color'] ?></option>
        <?php foreach(['ff000'=>'Red','3000ff'=>'Blue','36ff00'=>'Green','e400ff'=>'Purple','fff000'=>'Yellow'] as $key => $value): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" style="background-color: #ff0000"<?php echo setSelected($row['train_row_color'],$key) ?>><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="SAVE" value="SAVE" />
</form>


<script>
$(function(){
    // Listen for both change and submit
    $('.myform').on('change submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success:function(response) {
                if(response) {
                    //$("#fleet").load(window.location + " #fleet");
                    $('#fleet').html(data);
                    //alert(data);
                } else {
                    //$("#fleet").load(window.location + " #container");
                    //alert("Something is wrong with the update of the collor. Please notify an admin");
                    //alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Input fields are not in the same form as the selected. There are multiple forms. And every form is in a while loop. thus why i have myform '.$.' the same as the onchange($i)

Comment: You don't need to make a bunch of id-based forms. Use an `onchange` on a class. Saves a bunch of extra stuff you don't need.

Comment: As for the  `select`, you have `<input type="hidden" name="field" value="train_row_color" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />` nested inside the `select` which is invalid.

Comment: Ok that could be. But that is not the problem i was facing. The problem was the textfield didnt send the data. But i have solved it.

The problem was that i didn't closed the form tag with an (")
so i had this
<form method="post" action="" class="myform' . ++$i . '>
instead of this
<form method="post" action="" class="myform' . ++$i . '">

Answer (score 0):

Probem is solved. I didnt closed my form

```
<form method="post" action="" class="myform' . ++$i . '>
```

instead of

```
<form method="post" action="" class="myform' . ++$i . '">
```

My bad.

Thank you all for the time. and i will take an look at what @Rasclatt has given me as an option.

Answer (score 0):

use `echo` or print to set or bind values into text fields

```
<input type="text" name="value" value="<?php echo $row['train_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="field" value="train_name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```